# SwipeRefreshLayout from support lib. v21 doesn't work with static content

Tags: android, android-support-library, swiperefreshlayout

I'm using SwipeRefreshLayout from Support Library v21. It's work perfectly with scrollable content like List or ScrollView, but is't working with static layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Content"/>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

This code works well.

Video: **[Example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4jrczo7hu7b872r/movie1.mp4?dl=0)**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Content"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And that is not.

Video: **[Example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q84l5nff9emid31/movie2.mp4?dl=0)**

Is it possible to work with non-scrollable content in SwipeRefreshLayout?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What exactly is the trouble you're having?

Comment: The loader appears for a moment and immediately disappears

Comment: And this progressbar(loader) does not move from the top, but simply appears for a split second and disappears

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Update:

This issue has now been fixed in version 24.2.0 of the support library.

---

### Original Answer:

This is a regression in version 21 of the support library, caused by the fact that the drag calculation was [removed](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/commit/dc943d6192dab40df68b6b583c84e64045ea1bc8#diff-19b0cc7b7e876a53daf8f412147ab993L579) from the `onTouchEvent()` callback of `SwipeRefreshLayout`, and retained only in the `onInterceptTouchEvent()` callback. Therefore `SwipeRefreshLayout` works properly only when it *intercepts* touch events from a (touch consuming) child `View`. Interestingly, this issue was also present when `SwipeRefreshLayout` was originally introduced in version 19.1.0 of the support library, but was [fixed](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/commit/272acf0aa6bc9bf0d744b68a5b8b092c2c3e46d4) in version 20.

I have reported this on the issue tracker at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=87789

This can be patched by extending `SwipeRefreshLayout` and redirecting it's `onTouchEvent()` callbacks to `onInterceptTouchEvent()` until it returns true:

```
public class FixedSwipeRefreshLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout {
    public FixedSwipeRefreshLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FixedSwipeRefreshLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    private boolean handleTouch = true;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(ev);
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                handleTouch = false;
                break;
            default:
                if (handleTouch) {
                    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                }
                handleTouch = onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
                switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        handleTouch = true;
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```